# Amazon Free Tier vs Heroku Paid

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I'm building a new app that I will release on the iPhone. The app currently has just a few beta users but could grow exponentially like Instagram.

If I run PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS in production mode (with Multi-AZ Deployment & Provisioned IOPS Storage), Provisioned IOPS alone costs a minimum of $225/month. That's a lot!

Should I just use a cheaper Heroku paid option until expenses start to approach $225/month? Or, should I just go with the RDS Free Usage Tier option (Single-AZ Deployment & General Purpose SSD) even though Amazon says those configurations aren't intended for production?

If I should go with a paid Heroku plan, which should I start with?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty heavily opinionated answer, but it is also an opinionated question, so I hope you won't mind =)

In my experience, it is almost always better to use Heroku if you can. I have many reasons for saying this.

Firstly: Heroku dynos are reasonably priced. They aren't very expensive, and can scale on demand. They're also incredibly convenient to develop against, vs AWS services like ElasticBeanstalk, for instance.

Heroku has a MUCH cleaner developer experience, tons of plug-ins and addons beyond what AWS supports out of the box, and a consistent API / interface for working with these tools.

Next up: databases. While RDS is a great offering, it doesn't even come close to the flexibility or ease-of-use of Heroku Postgres. Heroku Postgres has been around for a very long time, is incredibly mature as a product, and has the single nicest database experience you can imagine:

- It's easy to provision new DBs.
- It's easy to provision new read slaves.
- It's easy to backup, migrate, destroy.

It's also reasonably priced, and will scale well with your needs.

If your main factor is cost (and you don't care about the hassle with operations / etc.), go with AWS. If time is your main factor, and you don't mind spending a tiny bit more in the long run: go with Heroku.

**SOURCE**: I've ran many production websites on both AWS (raw) AND Heroku that serve over 20 billion requests per month.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So, for Dynos, should I start with one Hobby ($7/month), or one Standard 1X ($25/month), or something more? And for Heroku Postgres, should I start with one Hobby ($0-9/month), or one Standard ($50/month), or something more? For both Dynos & Heroku Postgres, is it easy to migrate from Hobby to Standard when the app grows?

Comment: For dynos, use the standard (they won't go to sleep automatically). For Heroku Postgres, it really depends. How much RAM do you need? How much disk space? Start as low as possible, and work your way up. With Heroku Postgres it is REALLY easy to migrate to larger databases. It only takes your app offline for a few seconds.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It says the Hobby dyno also never sleeps, but should I still start with the Standard 1X?

Comment: So, if you want to use the hobby dyno that is fine! Just know that once you need more than 1 dyno, you will need to use the standard one. The hobby dyno only allows you to have a single instance of it running. So you can start there, just beware of that limitation! It's easy to change later though =)